# How to avoid commiting for DW dynamic files?

Tags: git, dreamweaver, commit, gitignore

While commiting git ask me to handle DreamWeaver dynamic files (*/_notes/dwsync.xml). There are lots of them and I don't know how to hide them because they are dynamic (so it's impossible to add them into .gitignore). Does anybody know how to solve that problem?

=================================

UPD after getting the solution

If you still see dwsync.xml appear, clean up the git cash:

```
git rm . -r --cached
```

it should help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to your .gitignore file, in the root directory of your repository:

```
[_]notes/
```

Let me know how you go, it worked for me.

Comment: Thanx, Dean. I need some time to make experiments. After that I'll tell you everything, I promise you! :)

Comment: ```_notes/``` Would work the same without brackets, [] is used to match multiple cases https://github.com/kenmueller/gitignore

Answer (score -3):

gitignore `_notes` dir?

You **have to read git-docs** in order to be able to use git